# Docmd.RunSql Run-time error '3464' - update query

Tags: database, vba, ms-access

I am trying to update access table using simple VBA code, however it finished with an error. I have tried various ways to solve it but without success.
Could you please help? The code is as follow:

```
strSQL = "UPDATE Projects " & _
          "SET Projects.id_status = '" & Me.T_project_s.Value & "' " & _
          "WHERE Projects.id_project = '" & Me.curr_open.Value & "';"
```

I have also tried:

```
strSQL = "UPDATE Projects " & _
          "SET Projects.id_status = [" & Me.T_project_s.Value & "] " & _
          "WHERE Projects.id_project = [" & Me.curr_open.Value & "];"
```

or

```
strSQL = "UPDATE [Projects] " & _
          "SET [Projects].[id_status] = '" & Me.T_project_s.Value & "' " & _
          "WHERE [Projects].[id_project] = '" & Me.curr_open.Value & "';"
```

But it asks for a data which is available in those fields.

Your suggestion helped. I started with only a text then I have changed particular variables I wanted to be read. So in the Where statement there is no need to have beside "" also '' :).

```
strSQL = "UPDATE [Projects] " & _
          "SET [Projects].[id_status] = '" & Me.T_project_s.Value & "' " & _
          "WHERE [Projects].[id_project] = " & Me.curr_open.Value & ";"
```

Thanks.

Comment: [How to debug dynamic SQL in VBA](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/418960/managing-and-debugging-sql-queries-in-ms-access/1099570#1099570)

Comment: Does your sql work when you replace your variables with real values?
Example:
`strSQL = "UPDATE Projects SET Projects.id_status = '3' WHERE Projects.id_project = '1';" `
Furthermore: Your fieldnames imply that you're using id's (often numbers) while you're sql is updating strings (with quotes).

Comment: So is your question solved? If yes, please post an answer or close the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once again, here is an example where parameterization (an industry best practice in SQL programming) helps beyond avoiding SQL injection. With [querydef parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff193967.aspx) you:

1. avoid the need of quote enclosure;
2. avoid string interpolation of variables;
3. abstract data (i.e., VBA variables) from code (i.e., SQL statement) for cleaner scripts;
4. (plus as OP found out with mixed types) explicitly define the data types of values to be binded;
5. execute the query via DAO for smoother user interface than `DoCmd.RunSQL` that raises warnings to users.

**Temp Query**

```
Dim qdef As QueryDef

' PREPARED STATEMENT, DEFINING PLACEHOLDERS (NO DATA)
strSQL = "PARAMETERS [project_s_param] Text(255), [curr_open_param] Long;" & _
         " UPDATE [Projects]" & _
         " SET [Projects].[id_status] = [project_s_param]" & _
         " WHERE [Projects].[id_project] = [curr_open_param];" 

' CREATE UNNAMED TEMP QUERYDEF, ASSIGNING PREPARED STATEMENT
Set qdef = CurrentDb.CreateQueryDef("", strSQL)

' BIND VBA VALUES TO PARAMETER PLACEHOLDERS
qdef![project_s_param] = Me.T_project_s.Value
qdef![curr_open_param] = Me.curr_open.Value

' EXECUTE ACTION
qdef.Execute dbFailOnError

Set qdef = Nothing
```

**Saved Query**

Even better, save entire prepared statement as a stored Access query and avoid any SQL in VBA.

SQL *(save as any regular query object whose name is referenced in VBA)*

```sql
PARAMETERS [project_s_param] Text(255), [curr_open_param] Long;
UPDATE [Projects]
SET [Projects].[id_status] = [project_s_param]
WHERE [Projects].[id_project] = [curr_open_param]
```

VBA

```
Dim qdef As QueryDef

' REFERENCE EXISTING QUERYDEF, ASSIGNING PREPARED STATEMENT
Set qdef = CurrentDb.QueryDefs("mySavedQuery")

' BIND VBA VALUES TO PARAMETER PLACEHOLDERS
qdef![project_s_param] = Me.T_project_s.Value
qdef![curr_open_param] = Me.curr_open.Value

' EXECUTE ACTION
qdef.Execute dbFailOnError

Set qdef = Nothing
```